# How to solve $F(z,q) = q + z F(z,q) + z^2 \big( F(z,q^2) \big)^2$?

Tags: combinatorics, functional-equations

Is there a method allowing us to solve the following functional equation ?

$$F(z,q) = q + z F(z,q) + z^2 \big( F(z,q^2) \big)^2 $$

Comment: What do you mean by solve?

Comment: I would like to find F(z,q)

Comment: Assuming that $F(z,q)$ is a power series in $z$ with coefficients polynomials in $q$, you can use the equation to determine the polynomials in $q$ one after another. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Somos No, I haven't tried this yet. Actually $F(z,q)$ corresponds to a formal power series with terms $a_{n,k}z^nq^k$. A coefficient $a_{a,k}$ enumerates rooted planar binary trees of size $n$ with $k$ being a product of outdegrees. So, definitely I can assume this, but I don't know how to how to proceed further, in order to obtain a closed form of $F$.

Comment: Does it help to know special cases like $F(0, q) = q$ and $F(1, q) = \sqrt{-q}$?       

$F(z, 0)$ is either $0$ or $\frac{-1}{z^2}$

Comment: You can recursively define
$$F(z,q;0)=q$$ and for $n\ge1$
$$F(z,q;n)=q+zF(z,q;n-1)+z^2(F(z,q^2;n-1))^2.$$
Easy to do with e.g. Mathematica. This converges to $F(z,q)$ as $n\to\infty$ in the sense the $z^m$-term no longer changes when $n>m$. It begins
$$F(z,q)=q+qz+(q+q^4)z^2+(q+3q^4)z^3+(q+6q^4+2q^{10})z^4+(q+10q^4+10q^{10})z^5+\cdots$$
Undoubtedly you knew about this. Adding it just in case.

Answer (score 2):

The question asked is

> Is there a method allowing us to solve the following functional equation ?
> $$F(z,q) = q + z F(z,q) + z^2 \big( F(z,q^2) \big)^2 $$

To solve the functional equation, assume we have a series expansion
$$F(z,q) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(q)z^n.$$
The functional equation then forces $a_0(q) = q$, and for $n>0$
$$ a_n(q) = a_{n-1}(q) + \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} a_k(q^2)a_{n-2-k}(q^2).$$
We can express this sequence of polynomials in $q$ as a finite sum
$$ a_n(q) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}b_k(q)$$
where $\, b_0(q) = q,\; b_1(q) = q^4,\; b_2(q) = 2q^{10},\; \dots\;$
are another sequence of polynomials in $q$
with positive integer coefficients whose polynomial expansion looks like
$$ b_k(q) = u_k q^{A073121(k+1)} + \cdots + v_k q^{3\cdot 2^k-2} $$
where [A073121](http://oeis.org/A073121) is a sequence in OEIS.
I think it is unlikely that $F$ has a closed form.